# 2 versions of tara ii no ni

Tags: grammar

What is the difference in usage and meaning of:

1. 行ったらいいのに =V/conditional
   and
2. 行けたらいいのに = V/potential/conditional

Can both be translated as "If only I could go..."?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

- `行ったらいいのに`: [I wish (someone) would go/You should go/You ought to go](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AB&dtype=3&dname=2na&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=03358200)
- `行けたらいいのに`: [I wish I could go/If only I could go](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%91%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AB/UTF-8/)

Comment: @cypher. It is impossible for 行ったらいいのに to refer to self, and for 行けたらいいのに to refer to others?

Comment: @Flaw I'm not sure, but I think they generally mean the above. Looking at the `うちの娘が...行けたらいいのに` example [here](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%91%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AB/UTF-8/), I think it may be possible for `行けたらいいのに` to refer to others if there's an explicit subject.

Comment: @cypher. Perhaps the one with potential i.e.　行けたらいいのに would have a higher tendency to refer to self because it is easier for one to assess one's own potential than another person's.

Answer (score 1):

`行ったらいいのに` is a suggestion, translated as "Why won't you ...". 
`行けたらいいのに` is translated as "If only I could go...", as you said.